# Issues with regex. nil slice and FindStringSubmatch

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to regex a pattern:

```
random-text (800)
```

I'm doing something like this:

```
func main() {

    rando := "random-text (800)"
    parsedThing := regexp.MustCompile(`\((.*?)\)`)
    match := parsedThing.FindStringSubmatch(rando)
    if match[1] == "" {
        fmt.Println("do a thing")
    }
        if match[1] != "" {
        fmt.Println("do a thing")
    }
    
}
```

I only want to capture what's in the parentheses but `FindString` is parsing the (). I've also tried `FindStringSubmatch`, which is great I can specify the capture group in the slice but then I have an error in my unit test, that the slice is . I need to test for an empty string as that's a thing that could happen. Is there a better regex, that I can use that will only capture inside the parentheses? Or is there a better way to error handle for an nil slice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually compare against `nil`, based on [the documentation](//pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.FindStringSubmatch):

> A return value of `nil` indicates no match.

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "regexp"
)

func main() {
   re := regexp.MustCompile(`\((.+)\)`)
   find := re.FindStringSubmatch("random-text (800)")
   if find != nil {
      fmt.Println(find[1] == "800")
   }
}
```